# Increase 4k buffer size for libfuse readdirplus?

Tags: fuse

Is there a way to modify or increase the size value that is passed to 
the readdir/readdirplus functions?

My implementation uses the low-level API.
With directories that are rather complex, deeply nested, or contain a 
large amount of sub-directories, I experience a performance impact from 
what seems to be due to the amount of recurring calls to 
readdir/readdirplus. It seems a buffer larger than 4096 bytes (which is 
what is passed in now) would help tremendously.

I've modified max_read, max_readahead, and max_write values but have not 
seen this have any effect.

Thank you in advance.